# join databases per column where data resides in different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get data from tables which sit in different databases but have the same schema.

I.E database names would be something like: DB1, DB2, DB3.

All of them contain the table 'MyTable' and have a foreign KEY that matches up to the 'MainTable' primary KEY in a DB we'll call MainDB, I would just do a union and worry about performance later,but the problem is, in this particular instance, sometimes DB3(or any of them for that matter) doesn't exist and that would cause my query to fail and need to be edited daily.

the MainTable has columns which when combined make up the name of the DB I need to join on each column, I'll call that a column called ForeignDBName for simplicity.
I want something like

```
SELECT 
  MainPK
, FName
, LName
, BirthDate
, ForeignDBName
FROM
  MainDB.dbo.MainTable
LEFT JOIN
  (
   SELECT 
     BirthDate
    ,MainTableFK
   FROM
     DB1.dbo.MyTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
     BirthDate
    ,MainTableFK
   FROM
     DB2.dbo.MyTable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
     BirthDate
    ,MainTableFK
   FROM
     DB3.dbo.MyTable
   ) B ON B.MainTableFK = MainPK
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not know how many of the databases you need actually exist, you would need to run some dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @statement nvarchar(2048);
DECLARE @db_name varchar(128);
SET @statement='SELECT 
  MainPK
, FName
, LName
, BirthDate
, ForeignDBName
FROM
  MainDB.dbo.MainTable LEFT JOIN ('

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
--adjust database names here
select [name] from sys.databases where [name] in ('DB1','DB2','DB3','DB4','DB5')
ORDER BY name

OPEN db_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SET @statement=@statement+CHAR(10)+'SELECT BirthDate,MainTableFK FROM '+@db_name+'.dbo.MyTable UNION ALL ';
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name  
END
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

-- we remove the last UNION ALL from the statement
SET @statement=LEFT(@statement,LEN(@statement) - 10)

SET @statement=@statement+') B ON B.MainTableFK = MainPK'

-- comment this to hide the statement that will be executed
print @statement;

--uncomment this if you want to actually execute the statement
--exec sp_executesql @statement
```